# Replace value in dictionary if the new value is a later date

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from a list. I want the value to be replaced if a later date is found.

Like this:

```
import datetime

values=[['A',datetime.date(2017,1,1)],
        ['B',datetime.date(2001,2,2)],
        ['A',datetime.date(2017,10,21)],
        ['B',datetime.date(2005,6,3)]]
d={}

for (k,v) in values:
   if k not in d:
      d[k]=v
   else:
      if d[k]<v:
         d[k]=v

print(d)
{'B': datetime.date(2005, 6, 3), 'A': datetime.date(2017, 10, 21)}
```

There must be an easier way with less code. How can i do this more efficient, maybe with dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a list of key, value pairs to `dict` it keeps the last pair if there are duplicate keys. So, you could first sort your list by the datetime values and then build the dictionary using that sorted list:

```
d = dict(sorted(values, key=lambda x: x[1]))

print(d)
{'A': datetime.date(2017, 10, 21), 'B': datetime.date(2005, 6, 3)}
```

**EDIT**

As @HåkenLid points out in the comments you don't need the `key` function in `sorted` since we only care about the order if the first element is the same anyway. So we can just say:

```
d = dict(sorted(values))
```

Comment: This but to make it more readable I'd put it on two rows (my personal preference). +1

Comment: You don't need a custom key function though. The default sort works as well in this case. `dict(sorted(values)))`

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is very readable as it is, so I wouldn't try and force a dictionary comprehension on it. Maybe simplify the `if` statement a bit?

```
for (k,v) in values:
   if k not in d or d[k]<v:
      d[k]=v
```

This works because `d[k]<v` will only be executed if `k not in d` has shown that that key exists.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with ternary conditional.

```
for k, v in values:
    d[k] = max(v, d[k]) if k in d else v
```

Or using `dict.get()` with default value.

```
for k, v in values:
    d[k] = max(v, d.get(k, v))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
{k[0]:k[1] for k in values}
```

Comment: This will not give the correct result if `values` is unsorted.